# Error when installing JSON 1.8.3 gem on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

EDIT, SOLVED:
This seems to be an issue when using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.4
 I added this line to my gemfile to get around it:
`gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'`
Found the solution here: http://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/7673

---

I'm getting an error when running bundler to install JSON 1.8.3 gem

Systen:
OS X Yosemite
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin14] installed with rbenv

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20170217-48653-1dn3hdt.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
>   make "DESTDIR=" compiling generator.c generator.c:861:25: error: use
>   of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
>       } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
>                           ^ generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
>       } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
>                           ^ 2 errors generated. make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/aakash/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I came across [this thread](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253) with a solution for Linux, which was to run

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

however I'm unsure how to solve this on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the whole thread that you linked? It suggests running `brew install coreutils` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I must admit missed that bit.
Gave it a shot, apparently it's already installed.


`workspace :> brew install coreutils
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'stable' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'refs/tags/1.1.10' which can not be resolved as commit?
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream refs/tags/1.1.10
Warning: coreutils-8.26 already installed`

Comment: I'm not sure what all that `fatal` noise is in your brew output. Have you run `brew doctor` lately

Comment: By the way, you may need to do some work to add the coreutils executables to your path.

Comment: This seems to be an issue when using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.4 
I added this line to my gemfile to get around it:
`gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'`
Found the solution here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/7673